# Can you create some type of library of "snippets" or "form parts" and insert into any of the forms that you are building?

Tags: cognito-forms

**For Example:** We use a specific contact information section, a specific table field layout, a file upload area unique to us and so on.

Can I save each out separately and pick from a library as I am building out a form?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment, no this is not a feature that Cognito Forms supports.

This is a good feature request. If you would like to be kept up to date on this request, please submit a [support request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/) and select 'suggest a feature'.